# Start a project in angular4 using cli

Tags: angular

I want to start an angular4 project using angular CLI command.
I have tried using command :

```
ng new angular-sample --ng4
```

But it is telling

> *The option '--ng4' is not registered with the new command. Run `ng new --help` for a list of supported options.*

And the above command creates angular2 project folder structure.

Is there any way to start the angular4 without manually editing the angular 2 versions(> 4) in `package.json`?

Comment: the command which you provided creates a new angular 4 project. what exaclty you want? to run this project type ng serve

Comment: Ok. so the best practice is to manually changing the package.json (> 4) and run npm install command rt?

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS , there is no such best practice , if you are pretty sure what you are doing then you can follow any way , package json is simple way to follow.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Angular CLI 1.0.0-beta.28 or less. Please uninstall it using following commands

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
```

Then do the global npm update by running the following command

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

if you want to upgrade your existing project then update the package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "tether": "^1.4.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
```

Note: This package.json is angular 5. Change it if you need angular 4.

Then run the `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new project using the cli it automatically resolves the dependencies to the latest version available in the npm. If you want to create a project with a specific version of Angular using the cli, my recommendation is to generate a new one and then manually downgrade the different versions editing the `package.json` file. But be careful because you need to edit the different angular packages (`@angular/common", @angular/compiler", "@angular/core", ...). After editing run:

`npm cache clean && npm install`

Comment: Thanks man. I wanted to make sure that there is no best practice other than manually changing the package.json and run npm install command.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is install any local version of `angular-cli` and then

In `package.json` make a script for ng

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng"
}
```

Calling `"npm run-script ng build"` will use the local version of the cli. 
It will work even if you haven't installed the cli globally.

> This way you can maintain different versions of angular-cli

For more detail : **[READ](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5955)**